# React + SQL Sever login form logic

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, reactjs, express

Hi I have been developing my own full stack login.

I have created a class to store users and now I am creating one to login from these stored users.

I have created a basic login form with a fetch to my server.js file.

However nothing seems to happen when I try and log in with this form.

I feel that the logic behind it makes sense but I cannot seem to figure out just why this does not seem to be working.

This is my class Add Users

```
class AddUsers extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { users: [], email: "", password: "", passwordConfirm: "" };
    this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.email.length < 8 || this.state.password.length < 8) {
      alert(`please enter the form correctly `);
    } else {
      const data = { email: this.state.email, password: this.state.password };

      fetch("/login-user", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          console.log("Success:", data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error:", error);
        });
      alert(`Congradulations you have signed up`);
    }
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.users);
    return (
      <div>
        <Formik
          class="form-signin"
          action="auth"
          method="POST"
          initialValues={{ email: "", password: "", passwordConfirm: "" }}
          onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
              console.log("Logging in", values);
              setSubmitting(false);
            }, 500);
          }}
          validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
            email: Yup.string()
              .email()
              .required("Required")
              .matches(
                /(?=.*outlook)/,
                "This is not a  outlook email address."
              ),

            password: Yup.string()
              .required("No password provided.")
              .min(8, "Password is too short - should be 8 chars minimum.")
              .matches(/(?=.*[0-9])/, "Password must contain a number.")
          })}
        >
          {props => {
            const {
              values,
              touched,
              errors,
              isSubmitting,
              handleChange,
              handleBlur,
              handleSubmit
            } = props;

            return (
              <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit}
                class="form-signin"
                action="auth"
                method="POST"
              >
                <div className="jumbotron">
                  <h2>Sign Up </h2>
                  <div className="help">
                    <Popup trigger={<Link> Help?</Link>} className="center">
                      <div>
                        Enter Codestone Email address and Password connected to
                        the account.
                      </div>
                    </Popup>
                  </div>

                  <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>

                  <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Enter your email"
                    value1={values.email}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ email: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.email && touched.email && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.email && touched.email && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.email}</div>
                  )}
                  <label htmlFor="email">Password</label>
                  <input
                    name="password"
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Enter your password"
                    value2={values.password}
                    value={this.state.password}
                    onInput={handleChange}
                    onChange={e => this.setState({ password: e.target.value })}
                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                    className={errors.password && touched.password && "error"}
                  />
                  {errors.password && touched.password && (
                    <div className="input-feedback">{errors.password} </div>
                  )}

                  <button class="button" type="submit" onClick={this.onSubmit}>
                    Sign Up
                  </button>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/login"> Login Page </Link>
                  </p>
                  <p>
                    <Link to="/reset"> Reset Password </Link>
                  </p>
                </div>
              </form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my server.js route

The error according to chrome is this first line

```
app.post("/login-user", function(request, response) {
  var req = new sql.Request();

  var email = body.email;
  var password = body.password;

  try {
    if (email && password) {
      req.query(
        "SELECT * FROM TestLogin WHERE email = ? AND password = ?",
        [username, password],
        function(error, results, fields) {
          if (results.length > 0) {
            request.session.loggedin = true;
            request.session.username = username;
            response.redirect("/home");
          } else {
            response.send("Incorrect Username and/or Password!");
          }
          response.end();
        }
      );
    } else {
      response.send("Please enter Username and Password!");
      response.end();
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    response.status(400);
    response.send(e);
  }
});
```

added chrome error

```
LoginPage.js:42 POST http://localhost:3000/login-user 500 (Internal Server Error)
handleSubmit @ LoginPage.js:42
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:336
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:385
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:440
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:454
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:584
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:609
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:713
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:722
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:694
runEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:739
runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:880
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:5803
batchedEventUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24401
batchedEventUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1415
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ react-dom.development.js:5894
attemptToDispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:6010
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5914
unstable_runWithPriority @ scheduler.development.js:697
runWithPriority$2 @ react-dom.development.js:12149
discreteUpdates$1 @ react-dom.development.js:24417
discreteUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:1438
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ react-dom.development.js:5881
```

I have tested the sql statement within chrome and seems to be working when hard coding the value in

Comment: What does `nothing seems to happen when I try and log in` mean? Did you try debugging the code? Was the server method called in the first place? Did the query run? What happens if you run the query using those parameters directly against SQL Server? At the very least try to log each step *on the server*

Comment: have added chrome error now sorry

Comment: does that help at all?

Comment: Not really - the only thing it says is that the server threw. What's the *server* error? You need to debug the *server* code. Something threw *outside* the `try` block. Perhaps `body` is undefined. Or the code inside the `catch` block threw, although that's unlikely